# How do you map routes according to the following schema?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How do you map this url
*/Topic/topicName/action?topicId=someInt*

Where **Topic** is the controller name (this is const - it always reads "Topic"),
**topicName** is being ignored
**action** is action name,
and **someInt** is the topicId argument for "action".

Here are couple of examples:
*/Topic/c-sharp/AddQuestion?topicId=1*

To invoke:
Controller: Topic
Action: AddQuestion
topicId =1

Where this is the action's singnature in `TopicConroller`

```
public ActionResult AddQuestion(int topicId)
```

Another example:
*/Topic/MySql-queries/AddSubTopic?topicId=1*

To invoke:
Controller: Topic
Action: AddSubTopic
topicId =1

Where this is the action's singnature in `TopicConroller`

```
public ActionResult AddSubTopic(int topicId)
```

etc. (all actions in Topic controller receive only one argument - that is the topic's id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Topics",
    "Topic/{topicName}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Topic", action = "Index" }
);
```

where you would have:

```
public class TopicController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult AddQuestion(int topicId) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and if you cared about the topic name you could have your controller action take it as action parameter:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestion(int topicId, string topicName) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still unable to set the defaults though. If you could help me yet again here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039886/maprouting-default-querystring-values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{topic}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Another way is to do it like stackoverflow. Take a look at question url, question is after id and is probably ignored.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this tool route debuger very useful to test my way around to the perfect route

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

it has also a nuget package now.
Might help for further scenarios, too...