# MapRouting default querystring values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route map (notice that topicName is ignored):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Topics", // Route name
               "Topic/{topicName}/{action}",
                new { controller = "Topic", action = "AddQuestion" });
```

And I want it to defaultly map to this Url: 
http://localhost:51421/Topic/SomeName/AddQuestion?topicId=1  (or if that's not possible,to this url: http://localhost:51421/Topic/SomeName/AddQuestion/topicId/1)
(which should invoke this action:

```
public ActionResult AddQuestion(int topicId)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

)
But either way I need all this data in the url.
What's the correct way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *default to an Url*? What Url do you type in the browser?

Comment: None. I want http://localhost:51421/ to invoke Topic's AddQuestion with topicId=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Topics",
    "Topic/{topicName}/{action}/{topicId}",
    new { controller = "Topic", action = "AddQuestion", topicId = "1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{topicId}",
    new { controller = "Topic", action = "AddQuestion", topicId = "1" }
);
```

Comment: I've been trying for ages to change the one you gave me earlier, instead of just adding a new one.. Will take awhile to get the hang of this.. :-) Thanks again.